# Советская Красная армия оскорбляет StackOverflow?

Tags: обсуждение, новогодние-шляпы

У меня была пафосная ушанка с красной звездой, но теперь вместо красной звезды лгбт-сердечко. Почему поменялась шляпа?

Советская армия оскорбляет SO?

В чатике еще осталась звезда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в профиле уже так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ответе подкинули [ссылку](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340512/383809) на обсуждение и где было принято решение о переделке.

Однако, среди шляп есть:

1. Шляпа пирата, которая так же может напоминать о злодеяниях того времени
2. Есть шляпы летчиков первой мировой войны

Если прогибаться под всех, то нужно удалить половину шляп.

Но я как бы отношусь к этому нейтрально и не ищу скрытых смыслов.

Давайте в таком случае знак добавления в избранное поменяем, как просят [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340612/670933):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он тоже может ассоциироваться не с тем...

Comment: единственное чего я не пойму, почему сердечко вы характеризуете каким-то образом относящимся к ЛГБТ

Comment: @AntonMenshov, не знаю. Ну не к месту оно. Лучше бы просто убрали символ. Это все равно, что сделать ушанку розовой.

Comment: Ну так попросите, чтобы для ru so эту шапку отрисовывали в первозданном виде.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Стоит также отметить, что данную шляпу собираются [удалить после зимнего мероприятия](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340512/this-star-on-the-warm-welcome-hat-looks-like-a-communist-symbol#comment1137956_340512).

Comment: А почему именно советская армия? Данная звезда больше на китайскую или северо корейскую похожа, так что скорее SE не любит китайцев :)

Comment: @AK Ну так не интересно. Нельзя даже сделать флешмоб с наступлением Красной армии на чаты enSO :)

Comment: @AK её удалят к следующей зиме вообще.

Comment: Сайт не отечественный, отражает *западную* культуру, следовательно "не нравится - не пользуйтесь")). Это видно на примере недавних событий с модераторами. Насчет Вашего вопроса - можно сделать *ersatz-mutze*,  т.е. *намертво приклеить* ее к аватарке в любом граф. редакторе. Тем не менее, с Вашим вопросом полностью согласен. Сердечко на ушанке вообще не к месту.

Comment: @iluxa1810, Спасибо, за вопрос, я думал это меня глючит, была звезда, а стало сердечко.

Comment: Тем не менее, я вообщем-то против  присутствия этого вопроса на этой мете. Давайте оставим вопросы полит-корректности и политики там, а здесь воздержимся от этой грязи и оффтопика.

Comment: слово "Красная" должно быть написано с большой буквы. Поправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Армия или Советская или Рабоче-Крестьянская Красная. А Советская Красная - не было такой ☝️

Comment: Мы живем в мире символов и ассоциаций. Если вы находитесь в узких рамках одной культуры, то вольны в ее контексте использвать/одобрять/осуждать символику. Если же вы в современном мире Интернета, то будьте терпимы, если кто-то относится к некоторым символам не так как Вы лично: у кого-то вызывает противоречивые чувства свастика, а где-то изображение фаллоса не считается неприличным.

Comment: а мне вот шляпа Amazing Grace немецкого орла с фуражек вермахта напоминает.

Comment: а мы свои шляпы можем делать?

Comment: @teran https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340615/373022

Comment: Эммм.... Что же ждет мой аватар и ник?

Comment: @Slavakamrad ничего? )

Comment: Ниче се. Я за этот вопрос на мете столько значков набрал =D

Comment: кто-то из админов решил получить ачивку "Декоммунизация" : )

Answer (score 30):

Эта звезда - это такая мелочь по сравнению с тем, что они дают шапку за ответ 21 декабря - в день 140-летия Сталина!...

Странно, что этим никто еще не возмутился... :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340758/hat-for-the-december-21-vote-is-this-a-joke#340759

Comment: Мда, это ж надо, что стёб могут принять за чистую монету... Воистину, суммарный интеллект человечества - величина постоянная, а население растет...

Comment: А вообще это все так глупо, что потроллю-ка я общество новым аватаром на один день - в знак протеста простив удаления красной звезды :)

Comment: И ник бы суффикс к нику Resistance Red Star ;)

Comment: @Harry Тогда может быть так — "Harry says Reinstate Red Star"? ;)

Comment: Решил тоже немного поменять свою аву...

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, Может лучше идти до конца - "Harry says Reinstate Stalin"?

Comment: @ВЛ 80 Не это перебор...

Comment: @Harry Хахах, а я повелся. * затролен *

Answer (score -16):

Да, достаточно большое число пользователей имели явно негативное или, как минимум, противоречивое отношение к предыдущей версии шапки "Warm Welcome".

[Вопрос был поднят на Общей Мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340512/383809), и практически в течение суток [дизайн шапки был изменен](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340579/383809).

На мой личный взгляд, старый дизайн, как минимум, противоречив с точки зрения его явного милитаризма (с теглайном Warm Welcome сочетается не особо). Однако, можно сюда добавить личные эмоции связанные конкретно с краснозвездной ушанкой.

Перерисованная шапка более нейтральна, и все равно несет коннотацию с Россией – только гораздо более тепло окрашенную: новую шапку я читаю как "From Russia with love".

Comment: Хм... ну доводы того вопроса так себе. С тем же успехом можно ассоциировать Scarf Ace, как шапку немецкого летчика первой мировой.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Доводы конкретно того вопроса действительно спорны, изложены не самым удачным образом и еще и были высказаны на эмоциях. Что не отменяет всего сказанного ниже, в комментариях, и здесь.

Comment: Шапка пирата у вас на аве напоминает о тех "зверствах", что пираты причиняли морским странам. На SE уберут её, если попросить?

Comment: @edem я предпочту остаться в дискуссии конкретно о той шапке, что вызвала проблемы и сподвигла минимум сотню людей проявить активность на Общей Мете. Если у вас новый вопрос, возможно стоить открыть новую дискуссию на этой или Общей Мете.

Comment: @edem +1. Если под всех прогибаться, то тогда все шапки нужно убирать, так как любой может чем-то оскорбиться.

Comment: @iluxa1810 если вас сильно задевает какая-то шапка, я думаю вам стоит начать новую тему на общей мете с объяснением вашей позиции. Ваше объяснение **и** реакция сообщества с большой вероятностью поможет исправить ситуацию.

Comment: Куда катится этот мир? Игры в демократию SO не доведут до добра.

Comment: @BarmaleysupportsMonica Вот вот. Всем не угодишь и кто-то вечно будет не доволен, а если под всех подстраивается, то это будет показыванием своей слабости и все сядут на шею и будут диктовать свое...

Comment: Согласен, по идее компания добавляет шапки монархистов/анархистов/лгбт/красноармейцев и проч. - хочешь напяливай, хочешь нет. А если возмущаешься анархисткой шапкой - то пшел вон - это мой сайт, чего хочу того и ворочу. Вместо этого начинается тягомотина: а давайте проголосуем, а давайте спросим к тасманийцев обижают ли их короны расейской империи? В общем полный бред...

Comment: @edem а может и правда нужно задать такой вопрос?

Comment: @Miron попробуйте, я уже засветился в этих обсуждениях там

Comment: @edem Только, вот, нужно грамотно все акценты расставить.

Comment: Ваш ответ неявно подразумевает, будто бы на SO есть правило, согласно которому то, что раздражает большие группы людей, должно быть убрано. В реальности же это крайне далеко от истины: SO использовалось и используется до сих пор администрацией как политическая платформа ([пруфы](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342440/276994)), и раздражающие многих сообщения висят и продолжают висеть. Следовательно, отношение пользователей является не причиной, а отмазкой.

Comment: @VladD и? я защищал SO по другим случаям? я утверждал, что есть правила и, тем более, что SO им следует? Факт: шляпа убрана. Я лично считаю что правомерно и по правильному поводу. Факт: SO делает много чего плохого. Факт: часто SO непоследователен. Факт: я с SO очень часто несогласен и уже участвовал в протестах. И буду, при этом придерживаясь активной позиции члена сообщества и модератора.

Comment: @VladD [офигеть...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand) еще к тому же и locked, мдааа по сравнению с этим монархические шапочки просто детский лепет

Comment: @AntonMenshov: Я не знаю, защищали ли вы SO по другим вопросам, тем не менее, сейчас вы их пытаетесь защитить. Факт: убирание шляпы не имеет ничего общего с заявленной причиной (пруфы этого в моём предыдущем сообщении). И я нигде не оспаривал ваше право протестовать, вроде бы.

Comment: Проблема не в том, что шляпа убрана. Проблема в том, что нету политической нейтральности. Моё мнение: если убираете шляпу, уберите и другие политические артефакты с сайта. Иначе «забота об обиженных пользователях» является ничем иным, как крайней разновидностью лицемерия.

Comment: @VladD я не согласен с вашей логикой, но думаю, что понимаю вас.

Comment: @VladD говорите об этом не гонцу (тому кто высказал предположение в форме ответа), а тому кто за это отвечает - хотя бы отдельным ответом, а еще лучше постом на МетеSE. А то опять получается мы тут окукливаемся - "какие все снаружи плохие, давайте говорить только друг другу как мы их нелюбим".

Comment: @Kromster о чём именно сказать? о том, что нету политической нейтральности, или о том, что администрация привирает? если вы заглянете в мой профиль, вы узнаете, что я не считаю более разумным тратить своё время и нервы на безрезультатные попытки возвращения SO на рельсы. _What is dead may never die._